# Getting source code of the page with UIWebView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

Hey I am making an app with the UIWebView and there are ajax things on the site. I need to run 1 ajax thing so the source code will change and after it I need to optain the source code. Anyway I could do this? Sorry if I explained it too complicatedly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can evaluate JavaScript within the `UIWebView`. Make sure to perform this after the page has completely loaded:

```
NSString *source = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                    @"document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML"];
```